# Correct usage of the $n^{th}$ term test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\ln(n)}}$$ I have rewritten it as follows $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\ln(n^{\ln(n)})}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\ln(n)\ln(n)}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{(\ln(n))^2}}$$

I tried using the ratio test, ending up with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-(\ln(n+1))^2}}{e^{-(\ln(n))^2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{(\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right))^2}= 1$$ so this test gives me no information.

I used the $n^{th}$ term test for divergence, but I am not sure I used it correctly. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{(\ln(n))^2}} = \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{(\ln(n))^2}} = \frac{1}{e^{(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n))^2}} = \frac{1}{e^{\infty}} = 0$$ by arithmetic of limits. Is this correct? How could I write it more formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alternatively*, one may notice that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
n^{\ln n} > n^2
$$ giving
$$
\frac1{n^{\ln n}}< \frac1{n^2}
$$ yielding the convergence of the initial series.

Comment: $n^{\ln n}=e^{(\ln n)^2}>e^{2\ln n}=n^2$

Comment: I was thinking about it! But I couldn't prove that $n^{\ln(n)}>n^2$!

Comment: but then I would have to prove that $(\ln(n))^2>2\ln(n)$

Comment: Observe that $X^2-2X=X(X-2)>0$ for $X>2$.

Comment: Is it becuase $(\ln n)^2 > 2\ln n \implies \ln(n) ( \ln(n) - 2) > 0 $ which gives $\ln n >1 $ and $\ln (n) > 2 $, so that we have $n >e^2$?

Comment: oh okay thanks ahah!

Comment: otherwise, would it be possible to use the integral test? I tried to use it, but I couldn't solve the integral

Comment: Yes. If you use the integral test you get to consider $\int_8^\infty x^{-\ln x}dx<\int_8^\infty x^{-2}dx<\infty$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa oh makes sense, I got till the substitution, but then I couldn't find a solution afterwards. Thank you! Just to know, as I've seen your massive integral evaluations (which I can't say I understood), how did you learn to integrate that well? Do you have books to recommend?

Comment: @Euler_Salter You are welcome! I did not have a particular book for integrals, but I was really attracted by integrals and series when I was a student ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49903/discussion-between-euler-salter-and-olivier-oloa).